# primeng overlay panel appendTo="body" alternative css

Tags: javascript, css, angular, primeng

I have an overlay panel from primeng, I am using `appendTo="body"` and it work fine in Chrome, but does't work in Internet Explorer 11. When I click it in IE the panel just doesn't appear, if I remove the `appendTo="body"`, it works fine in internet explorer but the panel is just off in the middle of the page. Is there work around this?

```
<button (click)="tagSelect.toggle($event)">Click</button>
<p-overlayPanel #tagSelect [dismissable]="true" appendTo="body" [showCloseIcon]="true">
       some content
 </p-overlayPanel>
```

[image: example]

css of .ui-overlaypanel

```
      display: block;
      z-index: 1019;
      top: 110.862px;
      left: 213.2px;
      opacity: 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had is the inline style in the button caused the problem, now I use `appendTo="body"` and it work fine in Chrome and IE.

```
<button style="float: right; position: relative; margin: 15px;">Click</button>
```

change to:

```
<button>Click</button>
```